# PHP Packages and Sub-Packages: What are they used for?

Tags: php, project, package

I've been using PHP for a few years now but I've never really used it for a large project, it's only usually little functionality upgrades I've given to websites.

I've just been given the task of developing a project in PHP and I've been looking at the code for some real world examples of my proposed bespoke system and they all start with @package or @subpackage

As I've said, I've never had a necessity for these on my small scale projects before and I would very much like to understand them more so I could use them to my advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels in comments that start with @ are used to generate the documentation by programs like [PHPDocumentor](http://manual.phpdoc.org/). In particular [@package](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.package.pkg.html) is usually the project name (or something like a big section of the project) and [@subpackage](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.subpackage.pkg.html) is a part of a @package, like a group of classes or a single class.

Comment: where would you define these packages and subpackages?

Comment: or rather how would I write a sub-package that defines the functions of my administrative area for example?

Comment: Those are file-level comments. This means that you must write them in a comment (using the phpDoc sintax (read the manual before starting)) at the begin of the files where you define your functions

Answer (score 0):

You define these @packages and @subpackages within the class docblock like this:

```
/**
 * Class description
 * 
 * @version    235
 * @changed    09/02/1971
 * @package    Intranet
 * @subpackage Client
 * @author     Micky Mouse 
 * @copyright  © 1960 Disneyland
 * 
 */
```